# Python xlwings - Copying sheets without deleting existing sheets in the Workbook

Tags: python-3.x, excel, xlwings

Here is my function I use to copy a sheet from one workbook to another. I want to keep the formatting as well so I did not use pandas. However, each time I run the script it removes all the existing sheets from within the `dest_book`? How can I stop it from doing that?

```
def copy_matrix_template(dest: str = None, src: str = None) -> None:
    src_book = xw.Book(src)
    dest_book = xw.Book(f"{dest}.xlsx")

    sheet = config_book.sheets["Copy This Sheet"]
    sheet.api.Copy(Before=dest_book.sheets(1).api)
    dest_book.save()
    dest_book.app.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just see that you defined `src_book` without using it. I double-checked it with the following code and it worked:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb_source_path = r"source.xlsx"
wb_dest_path = r"dest.xlsx"

wb_source = xw.Book(wb_source_path)
wb_dest = xw.Book(wb_dest_path)

ws_source = wb_source.sheets['Sheet_x']
ws_dest = wb_dest.sheets['Sheet1']

ws_source.api.Copy(Before=ws_dest.api)
```

Did you check if all the sheets you defined do exist?

Comment: well I found a way to do that without using xlwings, but rather just rewriting the entire page again using openpyxl which is faster than copying the sheets IMO